# I want to convert a date from String to LocalDateTime using DateTimeFormatterBuilder ()

Tags: java, java-time

does not convert the last digit of the date under the 16 index to

```
private LocalDateTime parseDate(String date) {
dateOut = LocalDateTime.parse(date, fmt);
```

an error appears:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '27 апр 21, 01:42' could
> not be parsed at index 16

I can't find the answer.
Thank you for your answers.

```
public class HtmlParse {

    private LocalDateTime lastDate = null;
    private LocalDateTime dateTime = null;
    private DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("d ")
            .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, new HashMap<>() { {
                put(1L, "янв"); put(2L,  "фев"); put(3L,  "мар"); put(4L,  "апр");
                put(5L, "май"); put(6L,  "июн"); put(7L,  "июл"); put(8L,  "авг");
                put(9L, "сен"); put(10L, "окт"); put(11L, "ноя"); put(12L, "дек");
            } })
            .appendPattern(" yy, HH:mm")
            .toFormatter(new Locale("ru"));

    public void setLastDate(LocalDateTime lastDate) {
        this.lastDate = lastDate;
    }

    private LocalDateTime parseDate(String date) {
        LocalDateTime dateOut;
            dateOut = LocalDateTime.parse(date, fmt);
        return dateOut;
    }


    public Post detail(String postLink) {
        Post post = null;
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(postLink).get();
            String name = doc.title().split(" / Вакансии")[0];
            String text = doc.select("td.msgBody").get(1).text();
            String date = doc.select("td.msgFooter").get(0).text();
            this.dateTime = this.parseDate(date.substring(0, date.indexOf("[")));
            post = new Post(name, text, dateTime, postLink);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        return post;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws SchedulerException {
        String link = "https://www.sql.ru/forum/job-offers/";
        HtmlParse htmlParse = new HtmlParse();
        htmlParse.setLastDate(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0));
        List<Post> list = htmlParse.parser(link);
        for (Post p : list) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The cause of the problem is the whitespace added at the end of the pattern. Replace `.appendPattern(" yy, HH:mm ")` with `.appendPattern(" yy, HH:mm")` to make it work.

Comment: `" yy, HH:mm"` (with no space at the end) works for me.

Comment: It's weird, but I still don't have it working like this `" yy, HH:mm"`

Comment: The reason for closure is not correct. It turned out that the problem was that the OP didn't know how to extract the date-time string from the text. Anyway, it was never a problem due to a typo because the OP was receiving the text as a result of web scraping. Please check the comments by the OP to get a better picture of the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have commented below the question, the cause of the problem is the whitespace added at the end of the pattern. Replace `.appendPattern(" yy, HH:mm ")` with `.appendPattern(" yy, HH:mm")` to make it work.

If the date string that your application is receiving has trailing or leading whitespace, you can remove it using [`String#trim`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) e.g.

```
String strDateTime = "27 апр 21, 01:42 ";
strDateTime = strDateTime.trim();
```

If your date-time string is embedded within some big text, you can use a [regex](https://regex101.com/r/vbY7M4/1) to extract the date-time string

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str = "Отношения между Индией и Россией были одними из самых глубоких дружеских отношений в мировой истории. 27 апр 21, 01:42 Русские и индийцы невероятно любят и уважают друг друга.";
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,2}\\s+\\p{L}{3}\\s+\\d{1,2},\\s+\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}").matcher(str);
        String strDateTime = "";
        if (matcher.find()) {
            strDateTime = matcher.group();
        }

        System.out.println(strDateTime);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
27 апр 21, 01:42
```

Apart from this, if you are on Java SE 9, I recommend you to use [`Map#ofEntries​`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-) for initializing the `Map`.

**Demo:**

```
import static java.util.Map.entry;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])  {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .appendPattern("d ")
                .appendText(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, Map.ofEntries(
                    entry(1L, "янв"), entry(2L,  "фев"), entry(3L,  "мар"), entry(4L,  "апр"),
                    entry(5L, "май"), entry(6L,  "июн"), entry(7L,  "июл"), entry(8L,  "авг"),
                    entry(9L, "сен"), entry(10L, "окт"), entry(11L, "ноя"), entry(12L, "дек")
                ))
                .appendPattern(" yy, HH:mm")
                .toFormatter(new Locale("ru"));
        
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("27 апр 21, 01:42", fmt);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-04-27T01:42
```

Comment: Yes, it's getting clearer. The problem is that there is a space after the date. So now the question is: how to remove this space in public Post detail (String postLink) { in: this.dateTime = this.parseDate(date.substring(0, date.indexOf("[")));

Comment: @Arvid, thanks for the help. Now we need to think about what to do next?  How to remove this space.I'm still trying to do it.